# only highlight the selected element, not its parents?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which seems to work except that now it highlights all the parents when a mouse is over an element. What I expected was only the element which my mouse is over will have a box drawn around it, the current solution draws around the element and also all it's ancestors.

```
  $("*").hover(
        function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).stop(true, true).addClass("highlight"); },
        function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).stop(true, true).removeClass("highlight"); }
   );
```

css:

```
.highlight {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF00FF;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF00FF;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF00FF;
}
```

this is the jsfiddle of what's going on, the highlight borders are "sticking" even after my mouse is not focused on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NE66P/419/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the event object passed in as the first parameter to your hover functions in order to stop the event from propagating. I haven't tested this yet, but it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*").hover(
        function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).addClass("Hover"); },
        function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).removeClass("Hover"); }
    );
});
```

Comment: this works but the problem is that the classes seem to "stick" after my mouse have long left. when I move my mouse around some of the elements still seem to retain the border until I move over it again.

Answer (score 1):

Use pure CSS without any JavaScript.

```
table:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Or you want this to apply to the table cells (`<td>`), not the entire table, do:

```
table td:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pure CSS?

```
*:hover
{
  //some code
}

table:hover 
{ 
  border: 1px solid #000; 
}
```